# Salida condicional resultados buscador

Tags: javascript

Estoy usando el buscador de Algolia en mi web, para ello tengo una plantilla personalizada, en la que muestro determinada info de los resultados de búsqueda, el problema está en que quiero utilizar if condicionales para mostrar o no determinada información, esto es lo que he probado pero no hace nada, directamente imprime los if como si fuera texto normal:

```
<script type="text/html" id="tmpl-instantsearch-hit">
    <div class="taxonomy-post" itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ListItem">
        <div class="cabecera-listado-cursos"> 
            <div class="meta"> 
                <div class="tag-formacion"><span class='[wpv-post-type show="single"]'>[wpv-post-type show="single"]</span></div>
                <div class="title-imagen">[wpv-post-featured-image size="full" item="@oposicion-academia.parent"]</div>
                <div class="fusion-clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="contenido-listado-cursos">
            <div class="title" itemprop="name"><a href="{{ data.permalink }}">{{{ data._highlightResult.post_title.value }}}</a></div>
            <div class="row">
                    if (data.metodologia != null) {
                        <span><i class="fas fa-chalkboard-teacher"></i> {{{ data.metodologia }}}</span>
                    }
                    if (data.empleo == "si") {
                        <span><i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i> {Bolsa de empleo</span>
                    }
                    if (data.campus == "si") {
                        <span><i class="fas fa-laptop"></i> Campus online</span>
                    }
                    if (data.tutor == "si") {
                        <i class="fas fa-user-check"></i> Tutor personal</span>
                    }
                    if (data.financiacion == "si") {
                        <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i> Financiación</span>
                    }
            </div>
            <div class="btn-wrap">  
                <div class="btn"><a href="{{ data.permalink }}">Ver más</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="fusion-clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</script>
```

La información que muestro mediante {{data.permalink}} si la muestra correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la forma de hacerlo, es bastante sencillo, hay que poner la condición dentro de la siguiente etiqueta:

Y el código funcionando quedaría así: `<# if ( data.metodologia != null ) { #>`

```
<script type="text/html" id="tmpl-instantsearch-hit">
<div class="taxonomy-post" itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ListItem">
    <div class="cabecera-listado-cursos"> 
        <div class="meta"> 
            <div class="tag-formacion"><span class='[wpv-post-type show="single"]'>[wpv-post-type show="single"]</span></div>
            <div class="title-imagen">[wpv-post-featured-image size="full" item="@oposicion-academia.parent"]</div>
            <div class="fusion-clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contenido-listado-cursos">
        <div class="title" itemprop="name"><a href="{{ data.permalink }}">{{{ data._highlightResult.post_title.value }}}</a></div>
        <div class="row">
                <# if ( data.metodologia != null ) { #>
                    <span><i class="fas fa-chalkboard-teacher"></i> {{{ data.metodologia }}}</span>
                <# } #>
                <# if ( data.empleo == "si" ) { #>
                    <span><i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i> {Bolsa de empleo</span>
                <# } #>
                <# if ( data.campus == "si" ) { #>
                    <span><i class="fas fa-laptop"></i> Campus online</span>
                <# } #>
                <# if ( data.tutor == "si" ) { #>
                    <i class="fas fa-user-check"></i> Tutor personal</span>
                <# } #>
                <# if ( data.financiacion == "si" ) { #>
                    <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i> Financiación</span>
                <# } #>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-wrap">  
            <div class="btn"><a href="{{ data.permalink }}">Ver más</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="fusion-clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```